# Prior statements not getting executed on sync ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a function like

```
function m1(){
    $('.loader').show();

   var xargs={
          type : 'POST',
          url : resourceUrls["listUrl"],
          data : "sId="+sId,
          async:false,
          dataType : "text",
          success : OnGetJsonCallback,
          failure : function(response) {
                 $(".loader").hide();
                 }

   };

  $.ajax(xargs);
}
```

here the problem, the loader is not getting shown before making ajax call. If I put a console log statement that is getting logged.

I did some searching and got to know that synchronous AJAX calls freeze the browser. But it can show the loader and then freeze the browser isnt it?

Comment: don't use sync ajax calls!!

Comment: Unfortunately its required for me here.

Comment: Why is it required that you use sync instead of async?

Comment: `.show()` is an async function. Sync ajax (oxymoron) blocks it before its end.

Comment: As @nordyguy pointed, i'm just courioius why you need sync call ? If you tell us, propably we can suggest you an answer to avoid use it.

Comment: Would sync ajax really just be jax??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did some searching and got to know that synchronous AJAX calls
>   freeze the browser. But it can show the loader and then freeze the
>   browser isnt it?

I disagree of doing this but you can listen to show complete and then make sync call :

```
$('.loader').show(500, m1);

function m1(){
   var xargs={
          type : 'POST',
          url : resourceUrls["listUrl"],
          data : "sId="+sId,
          async:false,
          dataType : "text",
          success : OnGetJsonCallback,
          failure : function(response) {
                 $(".loader").hide();
                 }

   };

  $.ajax(xargs);
}
```

Comment: No, it's called once show is complete https://api.jquery.com/show/ . This constructor takes duration and a callback function fired once show completes.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check [Specs](http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/).

So, instead of using a sync request you can acheive the same result using async request by implementing a **UI blocker** in your webpage. Just place a div of full width and height at a higher [z-index](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi5lYah8onNAhVDMI8KHWjIA_UQFggnMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FCSS%2Fz-index&usg=AFQjCNE1nRQxt8Qu7R8h-1GR3KRI8QteIQ&sig2=kmBALkli1u0hkGK8Xkmd6g) . And it will not freeze your loading element.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is single threaded, meaning that if anything is on the callstack, the browser cannot call a paint (and render the movement of the loader) since the render queue is waiting for the stack to clear up, hence the loader will not move only after the request is finished and the call stack is popped.

The nature of javascript is asynchronous since you should not block the stack in order to be able to respond to user interactions, thats is the reason of using callbacks and async methods.

1. I suggest that you figure out a way to use async instead of sync request. (you cannot be required to do such thing in javascript).
2. If that really is the matter, you can show a white screen with a static loading text on it. However, the screen will not animate or allow user interactions since the next rendering tick is blocked. (only until the sync request is finished).

to do so you have to write the following:

```
function m1(){
    $('.loader').show();

   var xargs={
          type : 'POST',
          url : resourceUrls["listUrl"],
          data : "sId="+sId,
          async:false,
          dataType : "text",
          success : OnGetJsonCallback,
          failure : function(response) {
                 $(".loader").hide();
                 }

   };
   setTimeout(function() {
      $.ajax(xargs);
   },0);
}
```

the reason for wrapping the sync ajax request in a timeout is to allow the browser to do a paint BEFORE putting the request on the stack and blocking everything.